# Animating UIView from Rectangle to Trapezoidal

Tags: ios, swift, animation, core-graphics

Please have a look at attached pic

[image]

Say I have a UIView as in first image and on user interaction, the rectangle of UIView should shape shift to trapezoidal.

I am exploring my options on how to work on to get this effect. Whether to use core graphics to draw my view or use core animation. But using core animation can a rectangle view be animated to view shape other than rectangle or square?

I can draw a trapezoidal view using core graphic but how to animate the rectangle UIView to a trapezoidal view.

Would be helpful if someone can provide a thought on how to achieve this effect.

Thanks

Comment: Look into `CATransform3D`. You can apply this transform to a view's layer to get the desired animation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
var transform3D = CATransform3DIdentity
transform3D.m34 = -1.0 / 1000
transform3D = CATransform3DRotate(transform3D, CGFloat(M_PI) / 4, 0, 1, 0)

UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.5, animations: {

    theView.layer.transform = transform3D

})
```